# Magento 2 visual swatch not showing in frontend

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, visualswatch

I created different attributes with visual swatches, and assigned each one to differnt attribute sets.

I have differnt products with different attribute sets, but for some reason visual swatches are not showing in frontend.

I have done this:

1- Update attributes on products

2- re-index, clear cache, upgrade modules

3- set to yes the option Use in Product List and Storefront Catalog Page

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong.
Do I need to add code in layout.xml or something related?

I followed this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-swatches-in-magento-2.html

Greetings!

Comment: all your step is correct, maybe you have some problem in creating attribute. You should re-do it again.